# How to force all activities in an application to always be destroyed (for testing purposes)?

Tags: android, android-activity, lifecycle

I am basically looking for the same functionality found in the DevTools (Development.apk) app that comes with the emulator.  I am wanting to perform similar testing on an actual device but the DevTools app does not work properly on the device I have so I cannot use it.

I am looking to test in a similar way.

What this does is causes each Activity to be destroyed whenever it leaves the screen, holding onto its instance state just as if the system needed resources and had killed it.  (So I can't just call finish)

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can kill your app's process at any time using the DDMS stop button.  highlight your application in the list and click the stop sign button.  your application will be destroyed like it was killed by the system.

See the stop button in the left pane(Devices) above each device listing:[image]

Comment: Perfect, easy, and it maintains the stack.  I love it.  Thanks so much.